# CSS content in rounded box

Tags: html, css

I have a container that has a border radius of 150px, the container has 300px of height and width.

I want the content to shape de circle, any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are new CSS3 properties which can do such things, such as `warp-shape` and `warp-shape-mode` but I don't think they are widely supported.

**[CSS Exclusions](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-exclusions/)**

Answer (score 0):

Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/qwbtq/1/

```
.circle {
    border-radius: 150px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    overflow: hidden;
    word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

Comment: I think he meant the content to fit into the circle warping inside of it.

Comment: I thought the same but provided this solution in case we were wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check this out:

http://www.csstextwrap.com/index.php